# Display ToolTip based on other DataGrid column

Tags: wpf

I have two DataGrids:
[image: Question]
What I need to do is when the mouse is over the green area, the ToolTip displays "lower_limit",
when the mouse is over the red area, the ToolTip displays "upper_limit".

The important thing, though, is that the ToolTip needs to determine which value to display based on the column [operation_type] and the corresponding value in the second grid.

Is this possible?

Thanks a lot.

post xaml code here:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgoperations"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" Background="#FFECE9D8" BorderBrush="#FFECE9D8" Grid.Row="1" MinRowHeight="30" IsReadOnly="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding  Path=operation_sequence,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="operation_sequence" Width="sizetoheader" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding  Path=operation_name,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="operation_name" Width="sizetoheader" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding  Path=operation_type,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="operation_type" Width="sizetoheader" />
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="parm1" >
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBox Text="{Binding parm_1}" ToolTip="Somthins display here. Values depand on value in column[operation_type]" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Hi Jacob: I am sure image had been uploaded, but i can`t see that in this page...

Comment: Would help if you'd post a bit of your code.  Are you using `AutoGenerateColumns`, or defining them yourself using `DataGridColumnTemplate`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) implementation for this; if you're not familiar, there's a basic example of how to use these at the link.  The basic idea is, you pass the data object to the converter, and it performs the logic and returns the correct tooltip text.

Your implementation should look something like this.

**XAML**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding parm_1}" 
    ToolTip="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyTooltipConverter}}"
/>
```

**Resource**

```
<local:MyTooltipConverter x:Key="MyTooltipConverter" />
```

**Code**

```
public class Converter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        MyDataType dataRow = value as MyDataType;
        string tooltip;

        // set tooltip to the correct value based on the dataRow
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```